# Querying Redshift from a AWS Lambda

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift

Pardon my english.

I have a spring framework,aws lambda based microservice. I need to query a specific table and  retrieve data from redshift. I initially tried this using spring-boot and jdbc template to execute my query which works. When I convert this to aws-lambda (java) and deploy I get `Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'jdbcTemplate';` I have the connection properties provided in the env.properties of the project, but still this issue prevails.

Is there a better way to do this ? Is there a way using serverless ?